# calling this._super() from inside setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, settimeout

We use John Resig´s inherit.js. And that gives us access to the convenient `_super()` function to call the parent´s function. That´s awesome, but today I was stumped by a problem, I couldn´t call `this._super()` from inside a `setTimeout`, even if I bound this:

## Code example

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
  this.dancing = isDancing;
},
    dance: function(){
        return this.dancing;
    }
});

var Ninja = Person.extend({
    init: function(){
        this._super( false );
},
dance: function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        // Call the inherited version of dance()
        return this._super();
    }.bind(this),50);
});
```

`this._super()` is undefined! What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this work you need to capture the _super method while in the subclassed method, like this:

```
dance: function(){
    // capture the super method for later usage
    var superMethod = this._super;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        return superMethod();
    },50);
};
```

The reason this works, and your code does not, is that the `extend()` method in inherit.js captures the superclass' 
method as `this._super` right before your overridden method is run. It then runs your code, and after your code has
run it restores _super to whatever it was set to before it ran. The action takes place in the following bit of code from inherit.js

```
      var tmp = this._super;

      // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
      // but on the super-class
      this._super = _super[name];

      // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
      // remove it when we're done executing
      var ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);        
      this._super = tmp;

      return ret;
```

So to be more specific; when the original code was run, the function that was used as a parameter to setTimeout was bound to the original object. The reason it did not work was that, even though `this` referenced the right object, `this._super` referenced something else, since `this._super` was reset to point to whatever it pointed to before the method was run. Probably it was not set, so the value of `this._super` was most likely just `undefined`.

Comment: Why didn't the `.bind(this)` part in the OP's code work to keep the right value of `this` in the timeout callback?

Comment: It did keep the right value of `this`, it was just that `this._super` is being reset after the method completes. Probably to undefined. I elaborated somewhat on it above. Did that (or the added info in the post) answer your question? If so, please upvote :)

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry for that. did not know about your 50K rep. just used to people forgetting it.

Comment: That's OK, I was just kidding around (I actually did upvote at the time of my previous comment).

Answer (score 2):

This shows how ugly [`Class` is implemented](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). The `_super` property will just be available during the time `dance` does run, and is removed (or restored) thereafter as it needs to be specific to the currently executing method. You will need to get the reference to the "current" `_super` value, and call that from the timeout. In short:

```
dance: function(){
    // Call the inherited version of dance()
    window.setTimeout( this._super.bind(this), 50);
}
```